# reverse an unsigned int number causing overflow

Tags: c, return-type

Enter a unsigned int, reverse it and see if its' still in range, if it is, print the reverse number, if not, print your number is out of range

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int a = UINT_MAX; // 0xffff
    printf("max unsigned int = %u\n\n", a);

    unsigned int x = 0;
    printf("please enter any unsigned int,\nit will show the reverse number if it's in range\n(enter 10 digit only)\n\n");
    while (scanf("%u", &x) != EOF) {
        //printf("x =  %u\n", x); 
        // above %d will print each UINT's binary oder, ex: enter 4294967292, x = -1 
        // if change %u, it will print entered number, ex: enter 4294967292, x = 4294967292 
        unsigned int temp = x, result = 0;
        int m = 0;
        while (temp > 0) {
            unsigned int digit = temp % 10;
            if (result > 429496729) {
                m++; //if reversed 9digits is already bigger 429496729, 
                //then 'result =  result * 10 + digit', it will have over flow problem.
            }
            result = result * 10 + digit;
            temp /= 10;
            if (temp == 0) break;
        }
        printf("m=%d\n", m);
        if (m >= 1)
            printf("out of range\n");
        else
            printf("result is %u\n", result);

        printf("\n");       
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _function returning itself_  =  *recursive function*

Comment: The recursive call has an "f" at the end of the name??

Comment: `reversePrintf` <-- typo ? Did you mean just `reversePrint` ? In this case - [cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/5Z9Spq)

Comment: thanks guys, i've notice the return function name was wrong, but now i wrote it without calling the function.

Comment: `x > UINT_MAX` can never be true. Also the scanf should test `== 1`, not `!= EOF`.

Comment: now i  enter certain unsigned int, ex: 4294967294, the reverse number is 4927694924, which exceed UINT_MAX, causing over flow problem, i dont know how to solve this over flow problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test for overflow is incorrect because you compare the `unsigned int result` with a value that is larger than the range of this type, so the test always fails.

There are 2 ways to check for overflow:

- taking advantage of unsigned arithmetics, you can compare is the result is smaller than the previous result.
- alternately, you can compare if `result` is larger than `UINT_MAX / 10` or if it is equal, if digit is larger than `UINT_MAX % 10`. This method works for all integer types, unsigned and signed.

Here is the modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int x;

    printf("max unsigned int = %u\n\n", UINT_MAX);
    printf("please enter any unsigned int,\n"
           "it will show the reverse number if it is in range\n"
            "(enter 10 digit only)\n\n");

    while (scanf("%u", &x) == 1) {
        unsigned int temp = x, result = 0;
        int overflow = 0;
        while (temp > 0) {
            unsigned int digit = temp % 10;
            if (result > UINT_MAX / 10
            ||  (result == UINT_MAX / 10 && digit > UINT_MAX % 10)) {
                overflow++; // the result will not fit
                break;
            }
            result = result * 10 + digit;
            temp /= 10;
        }
        if (overflow)
            printf("out of range for unsigned int type\n\n");
        else
            printf("result is %u\n\n", result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never return the reversed number, all you return is the final (rightmost) digit.

And your function doesn't "return itself", it returns the result of *calling itself*, which is not the same.

Comment: Also, you are printing the reversed number __always__.

Comment: i notice the problem, and change it a little bit, but now facing over flow problem if the reverse number is greater then INT_MAX

Comment: thanks, you are right, i return the right most digit~

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, much appreciated!
1. Regarding to "compare if result is larger than UINT_MAX / 10 or if it is equal, if digit is larger than UINT_MAX % 10. This method works for all integer types, unsigned and signed."

Is  (result == UINT_MAX / 10 && digit > UINT_MAX % 10)) necessary?
I assume input below digits
(reminder: only enter digit within UINT_MAX)

- unsigned int  4294967295 (10digit), reverse will be 592769492(4) /out
  range
- unsigned int  4294967294 (10digit), reverse will be    492769492(4)
  /out range
- unsigned int  4227694924 (10digit), reverse will be 429496722(4) / in
  range
- unsigned int  927694924(9digit), reverse will be 429496729 / in
  range
- the closest input is 3927694924 i can think of, and it will fit (result == UINT_MAX / 10 && digit > UINT_MAX % 10)) / in range

However, I've done the same for signed int, please see the code at below, but im not sure how to apply your method of signed int:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
    int x;

    printf("max int = %d\n", INT_MAX);
    printf("min int = %d\n\n", INT_MIN);

    printf("please enter any integer within -2,147,483,648 ~ 2,147,483,647,\n"
           "it will show the reverse number if it is in range\n"
            "(enter 10 digit or less)\n\n");

    while (scanf("%d", &x) == 1) {
        int temp = x, result = 0;
        int overflow = 0;
        while (temp >= INT_MIN || temp <= INT_MAX) {
            int digit = temp % 10;
            printf("temp is %u\n", temp);
            printf("result is %u\n", result);
            if (result > INT_MAX / 10 || (result == INT_MAX / 10 && digit > INT_MAX % 10)) {
                overflow++; // the result will not fit
                break;
            }
            if (result < INT_MIN / 10 || (result == INT_MIN / 10 && digit > INT_MIN % 10)) {
                overflow++; // the result will not fit
                break;
            }
            result = result * 10 + digit;
            temp /= 10;
            if(temp == 0) break;
        }
        if (overflow)
            printf("out of range for int type\n\n");
        else
            printf("result is %d\n\n", result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The test on the digit is indeed useless for the 32-bit `unsigned int` case, but it would be necessary for the 16-bit unsigned int case: `63556` causes an overflow, but not `53556`.  The test in 2 parts is completely generic, trying to reduce it for special cases is error prone.

Comment: For the signed int code, the test `while (temp >= INT_MIN || temp <= INT_MAX)` is always true. For the positive case, the code is essentially the same as that of the unsigned case.  For the negative case, it is more tricky: I would suggest computing as unsigned and negating the result at the end.